# How to stop address from populating autocomplete with google places

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-api

SO I have a google maps autocomplete on a form of mine, and when it gets a place it takes the place and formats it so that all the correct information goes into different inputs on the form.

The issue I'm having is before the 'place_changed' event fires the autocomplete populates the input. I want to prevent that initial population and instead populate with what I want to be there.

I tried doing a change event but it doesnt seem to fire correctly. Here is my code:

html:

```
<input type="text" name="address1" value="1255 W Washington St" required="" class="form-control" id="id_address1" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
```

js:

```
document.getElementById('id_address1'));
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'keydown', function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
            e.preventDefault(); 
            console.log('enter');
        }
});
google.maps.event.addDomListener(input, 'focusout', function(e) {
    if ($('#id_address1').val() != $('#id_address1').attr('value')){
        $('#id_address1').val($('#id_address1').attr('value'));
    }
});off"

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.address_components) {
        var address = '';

        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++){
            switch (place.address_components[i].types[0]){
                case 'street_number':
                    address = place.address_components[i].short_name;
                    break;
                case 'route':
                    address += ' ' + place.address_components[i].short_name;
                    break;
                case "locality":
                    $('#id_city').val(place.address_components[i].short_name);
                    break;
                case "administrative_area_level_1":
                    $('#id_state').val(place.address_components[i].short_name);
                    break;
                case "country":
                    $('#id_country').val(place.address_components[i].short_name);
                    break;
                case "postal_code":
                    $('#id_zip_code').val(place.address_components[i].long_name);
                    break;
                }
        }
        $('#id_address1').val(address);
        $('#id_address1').attr('value', address);
}
```

right now when the setting the attr and then checking on focusout is a workaround because when i select a place using just the keyboard it tries to input the original full string back in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trigger the blur-event before you set the value:

```
$('#id_address1').trigger('blur').val(address);
```

Comment: OMG. One million beers to you! Works like a charm.